# include and If statement inside a for each

Tags: ruby, if-statement, each

Clients can upload up to three files. I want to set the status of the  file based on the description they choose. The upload works fine and a static status is fine, but a dynamic one raises an error.

```
def build_document_objects
  [:first, :second, :third].each do |doc|
    d = "#{doc}_document"
    if self.send("#{d}_type") == "this Type"
      doc_status = 'one'
    else
      doc_status = 'two'
      self.send("#{d}=", user.documents.new(
        description: "Foo",
        file: self.send("#{d}_file"),
        document_type: self.send("#{d}_type"),
        status: doc_status
      ))
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get the following exception:

```
undefined method `save'' for nil:NilClass'))
```

If I do this:

```
 def build_document_objects
 [:first, :second, :third].each do |doc|
  # "first_document"
  d = "#{doc}_document"
  if self.send("#{d}_type") == "this Type"
  doc_status = 'one'
else
  doc_status = 'two'
  end  # change  where the IF ends
  self.send("#{d}=", user.documents.new(
    description: "Foo",
    file: self.send("#{d}_file"),
    document_type: self.send("#{d}_type"),
  status: doc_status
    ))
end
end
```

if the file description is not `this type`, the records will be saved. However, with:

```
    if self.send("#{d}_type") == "this Type"
```

I get the exception. The record will not be saved as there is no status present.

Comment: the error is the record will not save

Comment: ...specifically, the exception message and the line on which it occurred. Please edit to add that information to the question rather than elaborate in a comment.

Comment: ...and the line on which it occurred. Error messages contain valuable information. You need to study them carefully!

Comment: Presumably, there are several other methods involved that you have not shown us, such as `:first_document_type`. Since there is no method `:save` (that raised the exception) in the code you've given us, it appears that the error occurred in one of those other methods. If so, we cannot help without seeing the other code.

Comment: document type is simply  text input.

I am not sure of any other way to ask the question as the problem is in this part of the code - no where  else.  All I want to  to is assign a dynamic value based  on the result of a for loop 

  this  works somewhat if I change where the if loop ends - but does not  seem to pick up the value I want and change it

Comment: ("#{d}_type") == "this Type" ?? How is the string match for "this Type" is going to ever happen .. It is not an element of the array  [:first, :second, :third]

Comment: @NullSoulException It's not `("#{d}_type")` it's `self.send("#{d}_type")` so presumably `first_type` (and `second_type` and `third_type`) is a method on self.

Comment: "I get the exception the record will not save as there is no status present" ... this is a horribly vague sentence.  Can you edit your question to include the EXACT wording of the exception / error including (as Cary requests) the line number... which will be part of the exception message.

Comment: agree @SteveTurczyn ,the more the better ....

Comment: I am wondering if there is some confusion with the method [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send). `send`'s first argument is the name of a method, which can be expressed as a symbol or a string. The first time through, `doc = :first`, so `d = "#{:first}_document" #=> "first_document"` and therefore `self.send("#{d}_type") #=> self.send("first_document_type")`, meaning that you are invoking the method `:first_document_type` on `self`, but you have shown no such method. (btw, `self.` is not needed, as it is implied if you write `send(method)`.)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I am nuts

```
def build_document_objects
[:first, :second, :third].each do |doc|
# "first_document"
d = "#{doc}_document"
if self.send("#{d}_type") == "this Type"
doc_status = 'one'
else
doc_status = 'two'
end  # change  where the IF ends

 self.send("#{d}=", user.documents.new(

description: "Foo",
file: self.send("#{d}_file"),
document_type: self.send("#{d}_type"),

status: doc_status

))

end

end
```

works fine
the if just needs to be in the method properly.